# Best practice for message activity

Tags: android

Is there some android activity for message view, like how whatsapp and android SMS show the  messages (and even talk box show)?

I mean so that my message is on the left side and my partner's message is on the right side of the screen?

[image]

Comment: haha massage activity! that'd be cool. some super-vibration or something

Answer (score 0):

What you would do for that is a listview whose item´s provide different layout´s.

For example extra layouts for message´s that:

1. are written by you,
2. written by the other,
3. entry´s with information about the conversation

It´s really not to hard to build if you know how to handle listview and listadapter.

Good practice also!